# Read XML PHP DOM with XPATH

Tags: php, xml, dom, xpath

I have a question.

I have the xml

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=new+york&sensor=true

I want to read from example

GeocodeResponse/result/geometry/location/lat

and

GeocodeResponse/result/geometry/location/lng

maybe using XPATH and this is what i have so far ...

```
<?php

$Address = "new+york";
$Query = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=".$Address."&sensor=true";
$XmlResponse = file_get_contents($Query);

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadXML($XmlResponse);

$root = $doc->getElementsByTagName( "GeocodeResponse" );
foreach( $root as $val )
{
    $hrefs = $val->getElementsByTagName( "status" );
    $status = $hrefs->item(0)->nodeValue;

    foreach( $hrefs as $val2 )
    {
        $hrefs2 = $val2->getElementsByTagName( "type" );
        $type = $hrefs2->item(0)->nodeValue;

        echo "Type is: $type  <br>";
    }

    echo "Status is: $status  <br>";
}


?>
```

Can i have some advices?

maybe i can use

```
$xpath = new DOMXPath($xml);
$hrefs = $xpath->evaluate("/page");
```

UPDATE!!

I have managed to get the result by this ...

```
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$res = $xpath->evaluate('//GeocodeResponse/result/geometry');

$root = $doc->getElementsByTagName( "location" );
foreach( $root as $val )
{
    $hrefs = $val->getElementsByTagName( "lat" );
    $status = $hrefs->item(0)->nodeValue;

    echo "Status is: $status  <br>";
}
```

but i want something without foreach like

```
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$res = $xpath->evaluate('//GeocodeResponse/result/geometry');
$hrefs = $val->getElementsByTagName( "lat" );
$status = $hrefs->item(0)->nodeValue;

echo "Status is: $status  <br>";
```

Is this possible?

Comment: What is the problem? What doesn't work?

Comment: i dont know how to go further until i reach GeocodeResponse/result/geometry/location/lng

Comment: You have to create a new DOMXPath object: `$xpath = new DOMXPath($xml)`. Then you have to evaluate your XPath expression: `$res = $xpath->evaluate('//GeocodeResponse/result/geometry/location/lat')`

Comment: then what, do a $root = $doc->getElementsByTagName( "lat" );   ???

Comment: Then the content of the tag will be in `$res->item(0)->nodeValue`, see http://codepad.org/BtvNEnjl

Comment: hey, thanks!! now i have to retrieve for example first "address_component" and the name of the city, doesnt xpath have something like '//GeocodeResponse/result/geometry/location/lat[1]' meaning the second 'lat' from 'location'  ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to switch to JSON that is much easier to parse:

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/**json**?address=new+york&sensor=true

```
$json = file_get_contents('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=new+york&sensor=true');

$geocodeResponse = json_decode($json, true);

foreach($geocodeResponse['results'] as $result){
   echo $result['geometry']['location']['lat'].', '.$result['geometry']['location']['lng'] .'<br>';
}
```

Comment: JSON is also lighter on bandwidth and server resources.

Comment: It'll be better for **you** and **Google** ;)

Comment: because i get         Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/content/49/7991949/html/apps/friendlocation/get-city-coordonates.php on line 11

Comment: works, THANK YOU! so the conclusion is that ... just use json, its better, ok?

Comment: Wrong search query maybe? you can always `var_dump($geocodeResponse)` to see the structure of the response, also there is `$geocodeResponse['status']` that should be equal to `OK`.